# Display a message on Alcatel CLI before login

Tags: command-line-interface, switching

I would like to know if there is a way to show a message on the CLI when connecting to an Alcatel switch before it asks to enter login and password.

I'm doing that because I would like to set a custom ID for each switch and knowing the ID without having to log in.

(Another solution would be to replace the word login by the message I want to show)

Comment: The question is not about Windows, shell or putty, but on the Alcatel operating system (AOS) as what you want has to be made in the switch, not in your computer

Comment: @piertoni Thanks, is there any tag for AOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given right here :

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/207427/Alcatel-Lucent-Omniswitch-6850-48.html?page=83#manual

> Modifying the Text Display Before Login

> By default, the switch does not display any text before the login prompt for any CLI session.
>
> At initial bootup, the switch creates a pre_banner.txt file in the /flash/switch directory. The file is empty
> and may be edited to include text that you want to display before the login prompt.

With the following result :

```
Please supply your user name and password at the prompts.

login : user123
password :
```

**Old Answer**

I have found some information for you inside a manual of one switch:
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/207427/Alcatel-Lucent-Omniswitch-6850-48.html?page=82

> The Login Banner feature allows you to change the banner that displays whenever someone logs into the switch. This feature can be used to display messages about user authorization and security

> Two steps are required to change the login banner. These steps are listed here:
>
> - Create a text file that contains the banner you want to display in the switch's /flash/switch directory.
> - Enable the text file by entering the session banner CLI command followed by the filename

> [omissis]

> If you want the login banner in the text file to apply to FTP switch sessions, execute the following CLI command where the text filename is firstbanner.txt.-> session banner ftp /flash/switch/firstbanner.txt

> If you want the login banner in the text file to apply to CLI switch sessions, execute the following CLI command where the text filename is secondbanner.txt.-> session banner cli /flash/switch/secondbanner.txt

Comment: Thank you very much!
At first I was thinking that it wasn't what i was searching for because the banner only displays after logging in BUT, firstly it gives me a very good manual about the Alcatel CLI and going to the page right after 
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/207427/Alcatel-Lucent-Omniswitch-6850-48.html?page=83#manual
I find this "Modifying the Text Display Before Login"! And the example given is exactly what I am searching for!
So I finally found my answer with your help, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the pre_banner.txt file in the switch directory. This should solve your question